# Ionic app send form data to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have written a code to send the form data of an ionic application with angularjs to mysql. My code works fine, but only empty records are inserted to mysql
These are the codes:

**form.html**

```
<div class="list"> 
<form>
<div><input type="text" ng-model="h" ></div>
<div><input type="text" ng-model="s"></div>

<button ng-click='SignUp();'>SignUp</button>
</form>
</div>
```

**App.js**

```
.controller('SearchCntrl', function($scope, $http) {

 $scope.SignUp = function() {

 $http.post('http://www.qatarperfectmedia.com/channel/postdata.php',
 {'h':$scope.h, 's':$scope.s}
 ).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    if (data.msg != '')
       {
         $scope.msgs.push(data.msg);
       }
    else
       {
         $scope.errors.push(data.error);
       }
      }).error(function(data, status) {
         $scope.errors.push(status);
       });
}
})
```

**postdata.php**

```
 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
 $hospital = mysql_real_escape_string($data->h);
 $specialty = mysql_real_escape_string($data->h);
 $qry = 'INSERT INTO doctors (hospital,specialty) 
 values ("'.$hospital.'","'.$specialty.'")';

 $qry_res = mysql_query($qry);
 if ($qry_res) {
    $arr = array('msg' => "User Created Successfully!!!", 'error' => '');
    $jsn = json_encode($arr);
    print_r($jsn);
} else {
    $arr = array('msg' => "", 'error' => 'Error In inserting');
    $jsn = json_encode($arr);
    print_r($jsn);
}
```

The problem i face is when form submitted, only empty records are being inserted to database. Thnk you

Comment: On your server side do a var_dump($_POST) and check if you are really passing some data

Comment: it passes empty data

Comment: I did a post request to your URL and I got this: `{"msg":"User Created Successfully!!!,","error":""}` instead of the var_dump

Comment: where only empty records are inserted to database tabe

Comment: That's beacause you are doing something wrong on your php file, just put this on the top of it `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: Thanks, please check my code, i have added the php script as well above

Comment: You are doing a POST, this `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));` is not the proper way to get the POST data. Try this instead `$hospital = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['h']);
 $specialty = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['s']);`

Comment: Also mysql functions are deprecated use mysqli instead, check more info here -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: i tried replacing with `$hospital = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['h']); $specialty = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['s']);` 
still the same :(

Comment: At least could you put the var_dump($_POST) so we can see which data your server is receiving?

Comment: í cannot look the output of  `var_dump($_POST)` my friend,
because im running this page through phongap

Comment: It depends on your phone, it's an android with kitkat or lollipop? or it's an iphone?

Comment: its an iphone and im running the page through phonegap app

Comment: Here follow this link so you can debug your app -> http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/debugging-ios-phonegap-apps-with-safaris-web-inspector.html

Comment: Im using a windows machine, So i dont have safari 6 for windows.. im trying DebugGap

Comment: Without using `var_dump($_POST)`
i tried to echo `$_POST['s']` through an alert on my app. it doesn't contain any value in  `$_POST['s']` its empty

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out passing the values via url, and this works perfect

**html page**

```html
<div class="list"> 
  <form>
    <div><input type="text" ng-model="input.h" ></div>
    <div><input type="text" ng-model="input.s"></div>

    <button ng-click="SignUp(input);">SignUp</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('SearchCntrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.SignUp= function (input){  
    // enter code here
    $http.post("http://www.casda.com/postdata.php?first="+input.h+"&second="+input.s).success(function(data) {
      $scope.tasks = data;
    });
  }
});
```

**postdata.php**

```php
// get data from url
if(isset($_GET['first'])){
  $foo= $_GET['first'];
  $foo1= $_GET['second'];
}
// other query code
```